# Sqlalchemy + pandas: database session management

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm here because I need to know how pandas manage the database connection with read_sql and read_sql_table functions

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con_str = 'my connection url'
engine = create_engine(con_str, pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1600)

df = pandas.read_sql('select * from my_table', engine)
```

I would like to know if pandas open and close the session each time that I going to call read_sql / read_sql_table.

Comment: "The user is responsible for engine disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy connectable" https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Eric, sorry I miss that part, thank you.